# Yii Change field name

Tags: yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii-extensions

I want to rename the field. Code is here

```
 [['name'], 'unique', 'message' => 'This Make already exists'],
```

output

```
[
{
    "field": "name",
    "message": "This Make already exists"
}
]
```

how i change field? Result

```
"field" : "make"
```

Comment: you mean  show the "make"  label for the field  "name" ?

Answer (score 0):

Using `fields()`. In your model override fields() function as follows:

```
public function fields()
{
    return['make'=>'name'];
}
```

This will change the name of the field from `name` to `make` but your `name` field will be the only field returned. You can do all the tricks you want to append to the fields returned, or change them using this function though. To know more about fields check: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-model.html#fields()-detail